# tensorflow find index of the last occurrence of maximum value in a tensor

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Suppose I have a constant tensor like this `[[0,0,1,1,2,0][0,1,0,0,0,2]]`.

The index of the last occurrence of maximum values in `[0,0,1,1,2,0]` is `4`, and the index of the last occurrence of maximum values in `[0,1,0,0,0,2]` is `5`.

So What I want to get is `[4, 5]`, any ideas how I can do that? Thanks.

I'm using tensorflow 1.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a=tf.constant([[0,0,1,1,2,0], [0,1,0,0,0,2]])

max_idx = tf.cast(a.shape[1], tf.int64) - tf.argmax(tf.reverse(a, [1]), axis=1)-1

sess=tf.Session()

sess.run(max_idx)
```

The output is :

```
Out[137]: array([4, 5], dtype=int64)
```